# create beam elements and shell elements in hypermesh using TCL/tk scripts

Tags: automation, scripting, tcltk

I would like to create connector elements (1D- Beam elements) and 2D shell elements between two set of nodes which forms the edges of the two plates. How can I create this using TCL/TK in hypermesh.
I would like to select node sets only once and then perform both the operations.

Thank you.